# Cocoa document based app, NSWindowController subclass as "main window"

Tags: macos, nsdocument, nswindowcontroller

I have a Cocoa document based app. I want the "main window" to be managed by my subclass of `NSWindowController`. I have created the subclass and laid out its interface in a .xib file with the same name. I ultimately want the same behaviour as if the `NSDocument` managed the window, but instead have it managed by an `NSWindowController`.

First of all, how do I do it? Second, are the anything special I have to think about when going with this approach, such as how to handle open and save?

Comment: The window will always be managed by an `NSWindowController` class (or subclass) even in a document-based app.  There is a one-to-many relationship between `NSDocument` and `NSWindowController`.

Comment: Ok, but how can I change the `NSWindowController` object to be an instance of my subclass instead?

Comment: You'll have to check with a google search, but I believe you override `[NSDocument makeWindowControllers]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Override makeWindowControllers with your own windowController instance

   ```
   //Lazy instantiation of window controller
   - (WindowController *)controller {
     if (!_controller) {
         _controller = [[WindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Document"];
     }

     return _controller;
   }

   - (void)makeWindowControllers {
     [self addWindowController:self.controller];
   }
   ```
2. comment windowNibName & windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController methods

   ```
   //- (NSString *)windowNibName
   //{
   //  // Override returning the nib file name of the document
   //  // If you need to use a subclass of NSWindowController or if your document supports multiple NSWindowControllers, you should remove this method and override -makeWindowControllers instead.
   //  return @"Document";
   //}

   //- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
   //{
   //  [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];
   //  // Add any code here that needs to be executed once the windowController has loaded the document's window.
   //}
   ```
3. Change Document.xib File Owner Class from NSDocument to your WindowController

[image: XIB renaming]

From your WindowController you can send a message (call method) to your document class.

Also make sure you understand this diagram:

[image]

Comment: about that diagram... a NSDocument can have more NSWindowControllers, each having one NSWindow. Am i wrong?

Comment: in my case, my custom MyDocument has tens of outlets. It seems to me that, if I want to have a custom NSWindowController, I must move all of these outlets to my custom window controller, and refactor all of the code? That would be just crazy

Comment: This is because you have and existing app and you are starting your architecture late. You have to do a lot of refactoring. No other solution exists if you want to have custom nswindowcontroller

Comment: thanks i got that. I think it is apples poor design. when you have a complex app, you simply cannot anticipate that you will need a custom nswindowcontroller, 2 years later in development. eventually we found a workaround for what we wanted to achieve.