# How to implement a custom NSWindowController for NSDocument

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I have an NSDocument based application which works fine - but now I'd like to give it a customer NSWindowController so that I can implement NSTouchbar support for it.

Up to now, I've just used the standard NSWindowController provided by NSDocument - so this isn't something I have any experience of.  I've implemented a stub of NSWindowController, which I believe should be sufficient:

(document.h)

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface DocumentWindowController : NSWindowController

@end

@interface Document : NSDocument
.
.
.
```

(document.m)

```
static NSTouchBarItemIdentifier WindowControllerLabelIdentifier = @"com.windowController.label";

@interface DocumentWindowController () <NSTouchBarDelegate>

@end

@implementation DocumentWindowController

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];
}

- (NSTouchBar *)makeTouchBar
{
    NSTouchBar *bar = [[NSTouchBar alloc] init];
    bar.delegate = self;

    // Set the default ordering of items.
    bar.defaultItemIdentifiers = @[WindowControllerLabelIdentifier, NSTouchBarItemIdentifierOtherItemsProxy];

    return bar;
}

- (nullable NSTouchBarItem *)touchBar:(NSTouchBar *)touchBar makeItemForIdentifier:(NSTouchBarItemIdentifier)identifier
{
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:WindowControllerLabelIdentifier])
    {
        NSTextField *theLabel = [NSTextField labelWithString:@"Test Document"];

        NSCustomTouchBarItem *customItemForLabel =
        [[NSCustomTouchBarItem alloc] initWithIdentifier:WindowControllerLabelIdentifier];
        customItemForLabel.view = theLabel;

        // We want this label to always be visible no matter how many items are in the NSTouchBar instance.
        customItemForLabel.visibilityPriority = NSTouchBarItemPriorityHigh;

        return customItemForLabel;
    }

    return nil;
}

@end

@implementation Document
.
.
.
```

But now I don't know how to hook it up so that my NSWindowController (DocumentWindowController) is used by NSDocument.  I've tried creating a new object in the xib and wiring the Window to it - but that didn't work.  None of my DocumentWindowController methods work.  I'm at a loss!

Help me Stack Overflow, you're my only hope!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How to Subclass NSWindowController](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/KeyObjects/KeyObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179-CH3-SW10)

> **How to Subclass NSWindowController**
>
> Once you've decided to subclass NSWindowController, you need to change the default document-based app setup. First, add any Interface Builder outlets and actions for your document's user interface to the NSWindowController subclass instead of to the NSDocument subclass. The NSWindowController subclass instance should be the File’s Owner for the nib file because that creates better separation between the view-related logic and the model-related logic. Some menu actions can still be implemented in the NSDocument subclass. For example, Save and Revert Document are implemented by NSDocument, and you might add other menu actions of your own, such as an action for creating new views on a document.
>
> Second, instead of overriding windowNibName in your NSDocument subclass, override makeWindowControllers. In makeWindowControllers, create at least one instance of your custom NSWindowController subclass and use addWindowController: to add it to the document. If your document always needs multiple controllers, create them all here. If a document can support multiple views but by default has one, create the controller for the default view here and provide user actions for creating other views.
>
> You should not force the windows to be visible in makeWindowControllers. NSDocument does that for you if it’s appropriate.

Comment: But if I set Files Owner to be my Window Controller subclass, what happens to all the Files Owner methods which are Document, rather than Window specific? Do I create an Object for Document and wire up those methods there instead?

Comment: Connect to the first responder or connect to a method of the window controller and let the window controller call a method of the document.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Alas, it doesn't work (my own ineptitude, I'm sure).  I've put a test version here https://github.com/HeadBanging/TouchTest - are you able to suggest what I might have messed up?

Comment: You didn't do the second part "instead of overriding windowNibName in your NSDocument subclass, override makeWindowControllers".

Comment: Well I'm making baby steps towards where I want to be.  MY problem now is how to pass document data to the Window Controller subclass for display.  I've read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385088/cocoa-document-based-app-nswindowcontroller-subclass-as-main-window and this https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nswindowcontroller and more besides - and I'm still perplexed. windowControllerDidLoadNib isn't for me any more - so what do I need to do to get my successfully loaded data onto the screen? How can I call Document methods from my Window Controller? I'm being a dunce!

Comment: Use `NSWindowController`'s method `windowDidLoad` and property `document`. The window controller asks the document for the data instead of the document pushing the data to the window controller.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand (my apologies - I'm making very heavy weather of this!).  I've updated my test project on GitHub - https://github.com/HeadBanging/TouchTest .  It doesn't seem to work though.  The test should just open a text file and display it in its window - but that doesn't work!  Thank you for your continued patience!

Comment: The window controller you create is in the XIB represented by the file's owner. To make things work you have to connect the text view to the file's owner instead of the extra window controller (blue cube). You can remove the extra window controller.

Comment: Damn!  I thought I'd never get there.  Thank you so much - I'm very grateful to you.  That cracked it!